# Is this undefined behavior in C? (c=x) + (c==y)

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I have a bit of sample code that is throwing this warning:

```
main.c: In function ‘getline_’:
main.c:30:32: warning: operation on ‘c’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
```

In this particular exercise I was to avoid using the `||` and `&&` operator, but this doesn't seem like it should produce undefined behavior. The compiler message *is* just a warning, but I wanted to know for knowings sake. Is this code actually going to produce undefined behavior?

```
 24 int getline_( char s[], int limit)
 25 {
 26     int i, c;
 27     i=0;
 28     for( i=0; (i<limit-1) + ((c=getchar())!='\n') + (c!=EOF) == 3; i++){
 29            s[i]=c;
 30     }
 31     if( c == '\n' ){
 32         s[i]=c;
 33         i++;
 34     }
 35     s[i]='\0';
 36     return i;
 37 }
```

It seems to work ok in my basic tests.

Edit: Updated title as per comment, thanks pst.

Comment: Just because "it works here" doesn't mean it's *defined* behavior. The *UB* might be the behavior that you've always observed... (it could involve flying hamsters somewhere else, though)

Comment: Which is exactly why I wanted to know for sure, and came here. :)

Comment: Consider distilling the test-case (a warning can be generated with far less) and incorporating that into the title. It basically comes down to: `(c=x) + (c==y)`

Comment: probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc/16787634#16787634

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is unspecified behavior:

`(i<limit-1) + ((c=getchar())!='\n') + (c!=EOF) == 3`

the order of evaluation of expressions between sequence points is unspecified in C. It is unspecified if the assignment to `c` occurs before the equality check with `EOF`.

In addition to the unspecified behavior, it is also undefined behavior because it violates the sequence points rules and particularly this one:

> (C99, 6.5p2) "Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored."

Comment: Pedantic nitpick: But the warning say its Undefined Behavior not Unspecified Behavior, So...

Comment: Note to self, needs a dash of lisp. Thanks for pointing that out! Just waiting for the timer to vanish to accept...

Comment: So, am I correct in interpreting that sequence point rule to mean that it is invalid to have a variable assignment in that expression? Sorry if it seems like another silly question, c novice here...

Comment: Congrats because What you think is indeed correct :) and that is what the answer should say to beginwith.

Comment: It's not just unspecified; it's undefined. Because `c` is both written and read between sequence points and the value read is used for a purpose other than determining the value to be written, it's UB.